# How can Java's String.hashCode() function be used to make hash tables?

Tags: java, string, hash

Just started learning about hash tables in one of my classes. My understanding is that the way they work is the index of an element in the table should be determined with a hash function. I'm trying to make a hash table for a big list of Strings, and our instructor encouraged us to use Java's String method `hashCode()`. Say I want to put all of these Strings in an array, `words[]`.

Here's what I don't get. What am I supposed to do with that number? The hashes generated seem to be huge. The hashcode for "stack" is 109757064, and the hashcode for "overflow" is 529642498. That's a difference of of over 400 million, and would be a pretty absurdly huge table, not to mention how many indexes would have no String assigned to them. So I could have `words[109757064] = "stack"` and `words[529642498] = "overflow"`, but that's obviously ridiculous.

What am I missing here? Is there a step in between getting the hashcode and assigning it an index in my array?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is.

You start with that huge hashcode, and then hash that again to match the number of buckets you have.

Could be a simple `code % buckets`.

The [real-life implementation](http://docjar.com/html/api/java/util/HashMap.java.html) that `java.util.HashMap` uses is essentially that (`code & (buckets - 1)`), but they first apply another hash function to prevent some troublesome edge cases.

```
  257       /**
  258        * Applies a supplemental hash function to a given hashCode, which
  259        * defends against poor quality hash functions.  This is critical
  260        * because HashMap uses power-of-two length hash tables, that
  261        * otherwise encounter collisions for hashCodes that do not differ
  262        * in lower bits. Note: Null keys always map to hash 0, thus index 0.
  263        */
  264       static int hash(int h) {
  265           // This function ensures that hashCodes that differ only by
  266           // constant multiples at each bit position have a bounded
  267           // number of collisions (approximately 8 at default load factor).
  268           h ^= (h >>> 20) ^ (h >>> 12);
  269           return h ^ (h >>> 7) ^ (h >>> 4);
  270       }
  271   
  272       /**
  273        * Returns index for hash code h.
  274        */
  275       static int indexFor(int h, int length) {
  276           return h & (length-1);
  277       }
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Sorry if this is a dumb question, but what does 'buckets' mean in this context?

Comment: The number of elements your array in the hash table has.